# How to know which border is clicked in Javascript-WPF-C#

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, border

I have borders (buttons) inside a stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border MouseLeftButtonUp="selectStudent" x:Name="button_0">
        <TextBlock >Anna</TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <Border MouseLeftButtonUp="selectStudent" x:Name="button_1">
        <TextBlock>Bart</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

If `x:Name="button_0"` is pressed I want to change the `Visibility` of `x:Name="titel_0"` to `Visible` and all other titles stay `Collapsed`

```
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="titel_0">Anna</TextBlock>
<TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="titel_1">Bart</TextBlock>
```

I placed the borders and titles in an array:

```
var buttons = new Array(2);
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    buttons[i] = schermPage.content.findName('button_' + i);
}

var titels = new Array(2);
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    titels[i] = schermPage.content.findName('titel_' + i);
}
```

How do I start writing the `selectStudent` function?

I tried doing

```
function selectStudent() {

if (buttons[0]) {
    titels[0].Visibility = 'Visible'
    }
}
```

But if I press on another border it still shows `Anna`

Comment: What has this got to do with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This is what your selectStudent function would look like

```
void selectStudent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   string controlName = ((Border)sender).Name;
   //Write your if statement or switch case based on the controlName.
}
```